# Thumbnail with fading caption jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here:

http://www.latitude18films.com/webtest/international.html

All my Thumbnail with Fading Caption are working except casting directors...anyone here knows why?
you can view the source when right click on the page.

Here is my css code:

```
/*thumpnail css stylesheet casting directors*/
.itemCD {
    width:407px;
    height:247px;   
    /*border:4px solid #222;*/  
    /*margin:5px 5px 5px 0;*/

    /* required to hide the image after resized */
    overflow:hidden;

    /* for child absolute position */
    position: relative;

    /* display div in line */
    float:left;
}

.itemCD .captionCD {
    width:407px;
    height:247px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;

    /* fix it at the bottom */
    position:absolute;
    left:0;

    /* hide it by default */
    display:none;

    /* opacity setting */
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);    /* ie  */
    -moz-opacity:0.8;    /* old mozilla browser like netscape  */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;    /* for really really old safari */  
    opacity: 0.8;    /* css standard, currently it works in most modern browsers like firefox,  */

}

.itemCD .captionCD a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#585A5C;
    font-size:17px; 
    font-weight: normal;

    /* add spacing and make the whole row clickable*/
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    display:block;
}

.itemCD .captionCD p {
    padding:5px;    
    margin:0;
    font-size:10px;
}

.imgCD {
    border:0;

    /* allow javascript moves the img position*/
    position:absolute;
}

.clear  {
    clear:both; 
}
```

Comment: I guess you should post you jQuery rather than the css.

Comment: I tried looking at the source code and see what could be wrong but your code is overly commented and a bit of a mess, so it's hard to read. Can you post just the relevant part of the jQuery code?

Comment: That website is nice :D Glad your question got answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CD`code you are missing the `class` definition for the `img` tag replace with this following snippet and see that your Fading effect is back!

`<DIV class="itemCD"><A href="http://www.latitude18films.com/webtest/international.html#"><IMG title="" class="imgCD" border="0" alt="Casting Diretors" src="Latitude18films_files/casting-directors.jpg" 
width="407" height="247"></A>`

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yeah you were right Dave i was missing the class="imgCD" that fix everything thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `captionCD` is being positioned below the casting block.

If you add `top: 0;` to the `captionCD` class definition it works.

Comment: you are missing the `class` definition for your `image` tag in `CD` thats why the style is not being applied. See my answer too.